# Tail and wildcard characters

Tags: linux, bash

I want to get the last 10 lines of multiple files. I know they all end with "-access_log". So I tried:

```
 tail -10 *-access_log
```

But this gives me an error, where as:

```
tail -10 file-*
```

Gives me the output I'd expect. I would think this probably has more to do with BASH then tail. However commands like:

```
cat *-access_log
```

Work fine.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**I believe you would want:**

```
tail -n 10 *-access.log
```

**As to *why*:**
I don't think it has anything to do with globbing:

```
tail -10 foo-access.log arf-access.log 
tail: option used in invalid context -- 1
```

I think it just so happens that your glob expands to one file.  It probably has something to do with some archaic options parsing that I am too lazy to try to read, but if you really want to know go look in `tail.c` in the coreutils source and dissect the following function:

```
parse_obsolete_option (int argc, char * const *argv, uintmax_t *n_units)
```

Comment: or tail -n 10 *-access.log thanks for super fast reply!!

Comment: Ya, really you don't even need the 10 because that is the default.

Comment: fyi, it seems it has to do with globbing (please read my answer)

Answer (score 6):

While a  bit old, the question is still relevant. I met a similar problem

```
ssh myserver.com 'tail -2 file-header*'
```

that gave me the error

> tail: option used in invalid context -- 2

however, *tailing* only one file, like

```
ssh myserver.com 'tail -2 file-header-file-one'
```

works fine. Looking at the source *tail.c* shows that *tail* starts by parsing *obsolete* options, then parse the rest (i.e. options not processed yet), regular options. However, `parse_obsolete_option()` expects an "obsolete" usage, with only one file as argument.
So when providing more files, the function returns immediately, and let the regular parser to choke on `-2` (expecting `-n 2`).

```js
  /* With the obsolete form, there is one option string and at most
     one file argument.  Watch out for "-" and "--", though.  */
  if (! (argc == 2
         || (argc == 3 && ! (argv[2][0] == '-' && argv[2][1]))
         || (3 <= argc && argc <= 4 && STREQ (argv[2], "--"))))
    return false;
```

In conclusion, it is better to always use the `-n` regular form, knowing that the "obsolete" code only accepts one file.

Comment: Love that you dug into the source and found the root cause of this problem! But yeah, in conclusion, use `-n 2` instead of `-2` when there are wild cards.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this behavior of GNU tail(-COUNT only accepts one file) is documented. https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tail-invocation.html

> For compatibility tail also supports an obsolete usage ‘tail -[num][bcl][f] [file]’, which is recognized only if it does not conflict with the usage described above. This obsolete form uses exactly one option and at most one file.

It could also be found in coreutils info page installed.

```
shell> info tail
```

Note that on the contrary, "head -COUNT" supports multiple files.